# Bootstrap: make expand/Collapsible table instead of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

My Twitter Bootstrap version is 2.3.2

I tried making expand/collapsible table instead of div. Is it really possible?

**working with div**

```
  <a href="#expand" class="noline nowrap"
                   data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand">click to collapse and expand </a>


<div id="expand" class="more collapse">
 <p>data</p>             
 </div>
```

**not working with Table**

```
 <a href="#expand" class="noline nowrap" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#expand">click to collapse and expand </a>


<table id="expand" class="more collapse">

 <tr>
      <td>data</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Reference: [Here](http://www.bootply.com/bOx2M3vM6Q#)

Note: I cannot wrap my table inside the div because i need to achieve this inside another table.

Comment: On a side note, what you wrote for the div won't work. Unless you have the correct id: data-target="#expand-combine-multi-bl"

Answer (score 2):

Just put the <table> inside your <div>

```
<div id="expand-combine-multi-bl" class="more collapse">
    <table id="theTable">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Example here, forked from yours:
http://www.bootply.com/HU5VqyKpKR

As @Grimbode noted as well, the "data-target" in your anchor was not correct.

Comment: I cannot use div because i need to make it inside another table

Comment: I don't follow - why do you think you can have one table nested inside the cell of another but not a div? Using the above, you can place the div inside the cell of a parent table and it will still work; there shouldn't be any reason that the markup has to be table-> tr-> td-> table; it can be table-> tr-> td-> div-> table

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap the table in a div.

```
<div id="expand-combine-multi-bl" class="more collapse">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The reason it won't work with a table is because tables treat height like a min-height and will always expand to be as tall as the content within it